# LoadError: cannot load such file -- googleauth

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Included in gem file:

gem "google_drive", "~> 2.0"

I have tried using:

```
require "google_drive"
require "googleauth"
```

I am getting the following error. Please help.

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- googleauth
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in require' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in block in require'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in load_dependency' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in require'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/google_drive-2.1.2/lib/google_drive.rb:5:in <top (required)>' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in require'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in block (2 levels) in require' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in each'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in block in require' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in each'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in require' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in require'
/Users/tushar/Documents/../../../config/application.rb:23:in <top (required)>' /Users/tushar/Documents/../../../Rakefile:4:in require_relative'
/Users/tushar/Documents/../../Rakefile:4:in <top (required)>' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in <top (required)>'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in load' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in kernel_load'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in run' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:463:in exec'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in invoke_command'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in dispatch' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in dispatch'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in start' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in start'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/exe/bundle:30:in block in <top (required)>' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in with_friendly_errors'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/exe/bundle:22:in <top (required)>' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/bundle:23:in load'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/bundle:23:in <main>' /Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in eval'
/Users/tushar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `

'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It is there on my machine.

[image]

Comment: are you sure it's installed? Try running `bundle install` or `gem install googleauth`

Comment: @mrzasa I am pretty sure: 
    google_drive (2.1.2)
      google-api-client (>= 0.9.0, < 1.0.0)
      googleauth (>= 0.5.0, < 1.0.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.3, < 2.0.0)
    googleauth (0.5.1)
      faraday (~> 0.9)
      jwt (~> 1.4)
      logging (~> 2.0)
      memoist (~> 0.12)
      multi_json (~> 1.11)
      os (~> 0.9)
      signet (~> 0.7)
gem lock file

Comment: @mrzasa edited the question. Please have a look.